# Access a Button in Toolbar Pywinauto

Tags: ui-automation, pywinauto

I am trying to automate some of my office work and am new to pywinauto.
By running print_control_identifiers() I got the following in my application. How can I, for instance, access and click "Button - 'Open Project File'" which is under Toolbar?

Edited:

@Vasily Ryabov -thank you for your comment. I have added some code snippet below (commented line also works for me)

```
app = Application(backend="uia").start(r"C:\Program Files\Leica Geosystems\TruView\TruView.exe", timeout=5)
main_dlg = app['TruView']
main_dlg.print_control_identifiers()
# main_dlg["Open Project File"].click_input()
main_dlg.child_window(title="Open Project File", control_type="Button").click_input()
```

```
Dialog - 'TruView'    (L846, T0, R1895, B1038)
['Dialog', 'TruView', 'TruViewDialog']
child_window(title="TruView", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | Toolbar - ''    (L855, T38, R908, B1001)
   | ['ToolbarOpen Project File', 'ToolbarSaved Clips', 'Toolbar', 'ToolbarSave Project File', 'ToolbarSiteMaps', 'Toolbar0', 'Toolbar1']
   |    | 
   |    | MenuItem - ''    (L859, T460, R904, B505)
   |    | ['MenuItem', 'MenuItem0', 'MenuItem1']
   |    | 
   |    | MenuItem - ''    (L859, T413, R904, B458)
   |    | ['MenuItem2']
   |    | 
   |    | Button - 'Save Project File'    (L859, T367, R904, B412)
   |    | ['Save Project FileButton', 'Save Project File', 'Button', 'Button0', 'Button1']
   |    | child_window(title="Save Project File", control_type="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | MenuItem - ''    (L859, T321, R904, B366)
   |    | ['MenuItem3']
   |    | 
   |    | MenuItem - ''    (L859, T274, R904, B319)
   |    | ['MenuItem4']
   |    | 
   |    | MenuItem - 'Saved Clips'    (L859, T228, R904, B273)
   |    | ['Saved ClipsMenuItem', 'Saved Clips', 'MenuItem5']
   |    | child_window(title="Saved Clips", control_type="MenuItem")
   |    | 
   |    | MenuItem - ''    (L859, T182, R904, B227)
   |    | ['MenuItem6']
   |    | 
   |    | Button - ''    (L859, T134, R904, B179)
   |    | ['Button2']
   |    | 
   |    | Button - 'SiteMaps'    (L859, T88, R904, B133)
   |    | ['SiteMaps', 'SiteMapsButton', 'Button3']
   |    | child_window(title="SiteMaps", control_type="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - 'Open Project File'    (L859, T42, R904, B87)
   |    | ['Open Project File', 'Open Project FileButton', 'Button4']
   |    | child_window(title="Open Project File", control_type="Button")
   | 
   | StatusBar - ''    (L855, T1001, R1886, B1029)
   | ['StatusBar']
   |    | 
   |    | Thumb - ''    (L1869, T1012, R1886, B1029)
   |    | ['Thumb']
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L857, T1004, R1107, B1027)
   |    | ['Static', 'Static0', 'Static1']
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L1113, T1004, R1433, B1027)
   |    | ['Static2']
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L1439, T1004, R1639, B1027)
   |    | ['Static3']
   |    | 
   |    | Static - ''    (L1645, T1004, R1845, B1027)
   |    | ['Static4']
   | 
   | ...
```

Comment: It's good to provide the code fragment as well. Also marking correct answers as accepted is a good practice if you want to get help in the future on StackOverflow (there is no any accepted answers under your questions during years!). Gray check box at the left side of answer should work for you. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's guess your top level window specification is named `dialog`. It's easy to copy-paste code from `print_control_identifiers()/dump_tree()` output:

```
main_dlg.child_window(title="Open Project File", control_type="Button").click()
```

If `.click()` raises `NoPatternInterfaceError`, try `.click_input()` or `.toggle()`.

Comment: Thanks, Vasily.
Using your approach, how do I access  ```MenuItem - ''    (L859, T321, R904, B366)
   |    | ['MenuItem3']``` instead of the button itself?

Also, from one run to the other of that short code - run time changes dramatically and I can find myself waiting for almost a minute between 2nd to 3rd line in code. Why is that and how can be handled?

Comment: I think `main_dlg.ToolbarOpenProjectFile.MenuItem3.select()` should work. Or `.invoke()` or `.expand()` and `.collapse()`. Just call `.wrapper_object()` and do `dir(wrapper_object)` to list all available methods for returned wrapper. For production code `.wrapper_object()` can be omitted.

Comment: As fas as I understand from the print_control_identifiers() hierarchy above, MenuItem3 is not a child of ToolbarOpenProjectFile. If that is the case, how can it still be clicked?